# Vertical triangle commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to draw a vertical triangle commutative diagram:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow{r}{i} \arrow[swap]{d}{\varrho_x^f} & D(X) \arrow{d}{\varrho_x^g} \\
D
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

but I do not know how to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

I've added a column, empty in the first row, with `D` in the second cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    X \arrow{rr}{i} \arrow[swap]{dr}{\varrho_x^f} & & D(X) \arrow{dl}{\varrho_x^g} \\[10pt]
    & D 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]